# How can I insert custom objects into a std::map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl, insert, containers

I've read through the [map::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/map/) reference at [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/) and I'm still not sure how to get this to work. All I want to do is create a map like the following:

```
std::map<TriSpec, unsigned int> TriSpecMap;
```

Then I want to insert into it as follows:

```
result = TriSpecMap.insert(std::make_pair(triSpecObject, anUnsignedInt));
```

The following is a short example of my `TriSpec` header and .cpp:

```
//TriSpec.h
#ifndef TRISPEC_H
#define TRISPEC_H
class TriSpec
{
public:
    TriSpec(void);
    ~TriSpec(void);

    unsigned int m_position;
};
bool operator< (const TriSpec& lhs, const TriSpec& rhs);
#endif
```

```
//TriSpec.cpp
#include "TriSpec.h"

TriSpec::TriSpec(void){}
TriSpec::~TriSpec(void){}

bool operator< (const TriSpec& lhs, const TriSpec& rhs)
{
    if (lhs.m_position < rhs.m_position) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Am I overloading the correct operator? Is the function/formatting I'm using correct? When I look at `result.second`, it is always `true`, even when I know the object being inserted should already exist in the map.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not see any problem with your code except that bool operator should be friend method (it does not even compile without friend keyword):

```
bool friend operator< (const TriSpec& lhs, const TriSpec& rhs)
{
     return (lhs.m_position < rhs.m_position);
}
```

Then it works as expected:

```
int main(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::map<TriSpec, unsigned int> TriSpecMap;

    TriSpec triSpecObject1;
    triSpecObject1.m_position = 1;

    TriSpec triSpecObject2;
    triSpecObject2.m_position = 1;

    TriSpec triSpecObject3;
    triSpecObject3.m_position = 3;

    std::pair<std::map<TriSpec, unsigned int>::iterator, bool> retVal = 
        TriSpecMap.insert(std::make_pair(triSpecObject1, 1));

    retVal = TriSpecMap.insert(std::make_pair(triSpecObject2, 1));

    retVal = TriSpecMap.insert(std::make_pair(triSpecObject3, 1));

    return 0;
}
```

The result of first insertion is true, the result of second is false a the third is true again - as it should be. The map container contains two objects then - triSpecObject1 a triSpecObject3.

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't look like it would compile - your `operator<` doesn't return a value in all cases. (Edit: you've fixed this, thanks.) You can simplify it quite a bit:

```
bool operator< (const TriSpec& lhs, const TriSpec& rhs)
 {
      return (lhs.m_position < rhs.m_position);
 }
```

Since you don't show the complete code that inserts into the map, it's impossible to say why the return value `.second` always returns true.

Comment: Another reason it wouldn't compile is the `T C::(void)` function signatures (or whatever the correct form for member function is).

Comment: @moshbear: why would that not compile?  Isn't that one of the "features" inherited from C?

Comment: The code in OP's post was fixed since this answer came out.  You might want to revise your answer.

Comment: There are times I keep on forgetting that some of C's rather hack-ish features make it to C++ _and_  don't get deprecated in future revisions of C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

Since [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) you can also use a [lambda expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) instead of providing an `operator<` for your class. As a result, you can create your map with only two lines of code as follows:

```
int main()
{
    auto comp = [](const TriSpec& t1, const TriSpec& t2) { return t1.m_position < t2.m_position; };
    std::map<TriSpec, unsigned int, decltype(comp)> TriSpecMap(comp);

    TriSpec t1, t2, t3;
    t1.m_position = 1;
    t2.m_position = 3;
    t3.m_position = 5;

    auto retVal = TriSpecMap.emplace(t1, 4);
    retVal = TriSpecMap.emplace(t2, 2);
    retVal = TriSpecMap.emplace(t3, 6);

    for (auto const &kv : TriSpecMap)
        std::cout << kv.first.m_position << ": " << kv.second << std::endl;

    return 0
}
```

Output:

> 1: 4
>   3: 2
>   5: 6

[Code on Ideone](https://ideone.com/JbtrEL)